# is there anyway to automate routing in angularjs like .net Data Annotation

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

So I know how to work with routing system in angularjs, check this:

```
        .when('/96', {
            templateUrl: "96.html",
            animation: 'present'
        })
        .when('/96/moharram', {
            templateUrl: "96_moharram.html",
            animation: 'present'
        })
        .when('/96/safar', {
            templateUrl: "96_safar.html",
            animation: 'present'
        })
        .when('/96/shaban', {
            templateUrl: "96_shaban.html",
            animation: 'present'
        })
        .when('/96/shaban/01', {
            templateUrl: "96_shaban_01.html",
            animation: 'present'
        })
        .when('/96/shaban/02', {
            templateUrl: "96_shaban_02.html",
            animation: 'present'
        })
        .when('/95', {
            templateUrl:  "95.html",
            animation: 'past'
        })
```

So far there is no problem. But the concept is to create 12 months a year and almost 30 days a month. So is there anyway that i can say for example when the page is in "/96" (and on every other year) when user clicked on moharram (the month) the page should goes to /96_mohrram.html or /96/moharram.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*templateUrl* may be a function that takes as an argument [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams). Given that and path parameterization, here's an example of what you may be looking for:

```
.when('/:year/:month', {
    templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
        return $routeParams['year'] + "/" $routeParams['month'] + ".html"
    },
    animation: 'past'
})
```

Read more about [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: everytime I try your code it gives me an ODD 404 error: :63342/beiraq.com/beiraq.com/index.html.html. and whole app crashes.